# About Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, gronwall-type-inequality

I knew the following Gronwall's inequality (Integral form)

If $\alpha$ is non-negative and $H(t)$ satisfies the integral inequality

\begin{align*}
H(t) \leq c+ \int_0^t \alpha(s) H(s)ds \quad \text{(c: constant)},
\end{align*}

then

\begin{align*}
H(t) \leq c \exp \left( \int_0^t \alpha(s) ds \right).
\end{align*}

But, I wonder whether there are some Gronwall-type inequalities below :

**New Version** If $H(t)$ satisfies the integral inequality
\begin{align*}
H(t) \leq c + \int_0^t \color{red}{\alpha(t,s)} H(s) ds,
\end{align*}
then it holds
\begin{align*}
H(t) \leq c \exp \left( \int_0^t \alpha(t,s) ds\right).
\end{align*}

(Specifically, in my case, $\alpha(t,s) = (1+(t-s)^{-1/2}) e^{-s}$.)

I'm curious whether Gronwall type inequality mentioned above can be established, and if not, whether it can be applicable in my case. I would appreciate it if you could provide references or assistance.

Comment: Gronwall inequality of this type are studied here, for example: https://rgmia.org/papers/monographs/standard.pdf However the kernel function there are mostly continuous, so I dont't know if your case is covered.

Comment: @Gerd As you mentioned, my case does not satisfy the assumption in the Theorem... Thank you for providing good reference!